# Recursion loop to check if conditions good, or try again

Tags: javascript, loops, object, recursion, canvas

I have to generate several objects on a canvas.
The **problem** is that if my conditions (IF statements) are working, it is not looping again if the conditions are not met.
So I sometimes have only 1 player instead of 2, etc.

The function which sets the piece is setPiece(), with different conditions depending of the objects (obstacle, weapon, player).
Each object has in own function which call setPiece: setObstacles, setWeapons, setPlayers.

I have already tried to **call these functions after an "else"**, so setPiece loop again. But it causes a stack error in the console, too many loops.

I also tried a **While loop** but don't succeded to implement it, so it is also an infinite loop.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-compatible" content="IE-edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.0/animate.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <title>Lava Temple</title>

<style>
* {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

body{
  background-color: #181818;
}

#board {
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="board" width="800" height="800"></canvas>

<script>

// BOARD OBJECT

function Board(width, height) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.chartBoard = [];

    // Création du plateau logique
    for (var i = 0; i < this.width; i++) {
        const row = [];
        this.chartBoard.push(row);
        for (var j = 0; j < this.height; j++) {
            const col = {};
            row.push(col);
        }
    }
}

let board = new Board(10, 10);
console.log(board);

const ctx = $('#board').get(0).getContext('2d');

Board.prototype.drawBoard = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.width; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < this.height; j++) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
            ctx.strokeRect(j * 64, i * 64, 64, 64);
            ctx.closePath();
        }
    }
};
board.drawBoard();



// OBJECTS OF THE GAME

function Obstacle(name, sprite) {
    this.name = name;
    this.sprite = sprite;
}
const lava = new Obstacle("Lave", "assets/lave.png");
const lava1 = new Obstacle("Lave1", "assets/lave.png");
const lava2 = new Obstacle("Lave2", "assets/lave.png");
const lava3 = new Obstacle("Lave3", "assets/lave.png");
const lava4 = new Obstacle("Lave4", "assets/lave.png");
const lava5 = new Obstacle("Lave5", "assets/lave.png");
const lava6 = new Obstacle("Lave6", "assets/lave.png");
const lava7 = new Obstacle("Lave7", "assets/lave.png");
const lava8 = new Obstacle("Lave8", "assets/lave.png");
const lava9 = new Obstacle("Lave9", "assets/lave.png");
const lavaArray = [lava, lava1, lava2, lava3, lava4, lava5, lava6, lava7, lava8, lava9];


function Weapon(name, sprite, damage) {
    this.name = name;
    this.sprite = sprite;
    this.damage = damage;
}
const dagger = new Weapon("Dague", "assets/dague.png", 5);
const sword = new Weapon("Epée", "assets/epee.png", 10);
const axe = new Weapon("Hache", "assets/hache.png", 15);
const flail = new Weapon("Fléau", "assets/fleau.png", 20);
const weaponArray = [dagger, sword, axe, flail];


function Player(name, sprite, life) {
    this.name = name;
    this.sprite = sprite;
    this.life = life;
}
const player1 = new Player("Joueur 1", "assets/joueur1.png", 100);
const player2 = new Player("Joueur 2", "assets/joueur2.png", 100);
const playerArray = [player1, player2];



// INIT OF THE GAME (code about my question)

Board.prototype.setPiece = function (piece) {

    let randomX = Math.floor(Math.random() * board.width);
    let randomY = Math.floor(Math.random() * board.height);

    let drawX = randomX * 64;
    let drawY = randomY * 64;


    if (randomX >= this.width || randomY >= this.height) {
        throw new Error('Pièce hors limite');
    }

    if (piece instanceof Obstacle) {

        if (!(this.chartBoard[randomY][randomX] instanceof Obstacle)) {
            this.chartBoard[randomY][randomX] = piece;
              ctx.fillRect(drawX, drawY,64,64);
        }

    } else if (piece instanceof Weapon) {

        if (!(this.chartBoard[randomY][randomX] instanceof Obstacle) && (!(this.chartBoard[randomY][randomX] instanceof Weapon))) {
            this.chartBoard[randomY][randomX] = piece;
            ctx.fillStyle = "red";
            ctx.fillRect(drawX, drawY,64,64);
        }

    } else if (piece instanceof Player) {

            if  (!(this.chartBoard[randomY][randomX] instanceof Obstacle) &&
                (!(this.chartBoard[randomY][randomX] instanceof Weapon) &&
                (!(this.chartBoard[randomY][randomX] instanceof Player) &&
                ((!(this.chartBoard[randomY][randomX + 1] instanceof Player)) || (typeof this.chartBoard[randomY][randomX + 1] === undefined)) &&
                ((!(this.chartBoard[randomY][randomX - 1] instanceof Player)) || (typeof this.chartBoard[randomY][randomX - 1] === undefined)) &&
                ((!(this.chartBoard[randomY + 1][randomX] instanceof Player)) || (typeof this.chartBoard[randomY + 1][randomX] === undefined)) &&
                ((!(this.chartBoard[randomY - 1][randomX] instanceof Player)) || (typeof this.chartBoard[randomY - 1][randomX] === undefined))))) {

                this.chartBoard[randomY][randomX] = piece;
                ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
                ctx.fillRect(drawX, drawY,64,64);
            }

    } else {
        throw new Error('Pièce non valide');
    }
};


Board.prototype.setObstacles = function () {
    for (let lava of lavaArray) {

        const obstacle = board.setPiece(lava);
    }
};
board.setObstacles();


Board.prototype.setWeapons = function () {
    let numWeapons = 4;
    let randomWeapon;
    let spawnWeapon;

    for (let i = 0; i < numWeapons; i++) {
        randomWeapon = Math.floor(Math.random() * weaponArray.length);
        spawnWeapon = board.setPiece(weaponArray[randomWeapon]);
    }
};
board.setWeapons();


Board.prototype.setPlayers = function () {

    for (let player of playerArray) {

        const spawnPlayer = board.setPiece(player);
    }
};
board.setPlayers();

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Actual results:** Sometimes everything works well, but there are 2 problems:
- A piece might not be set on the board (canvas).
- There is an error with the player object because the IF condition (random + or - x / y) try to check outside of the length of the board, so I get an error Undefined. Don't know how to resolve it.

**Expected:** Understand how to generate a dynamic generation of objects on this canvas, and to repeat a loop with multiple conditions. Also learn how to implement the limits of the canvas so there is no Undefined error.

Comment: Sidenote: Please don't abuse emphases.

Comment: @hindmost Ok, I reduced them. It's just to make the text easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with going out of boundaries with on of those randomY increments and decrements. If you console.log(randomY) right after `else if (piece instanceof Player) { ...` then it seems that you get only one player in those scenarios only when randomY is either 0 or 9.

You can try doing something along these lines right after `else if (piece instanceof Player) { ...` and this should resolve the issue.

```
if (randomY === 0){
  randomY = randomY+1
}

if (randomY === 9){
  randomY = randomY-1
}
```

I'm not sure if this would still be considered "random". Tiles would still be able to take edges though, so mechanics still feel "random".

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but still have problems with the edges. 

Maybe I should make a copy of this.chartBoard, then randomX and Y would choose a value within those still remaining.
But I don't know how to do it.